# Importing entries from a txt file into a list. Problem with format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a problem with importing entries to a list from a .txt file. Format of a data in .txt is:

```
Afghanistan | Kabul
Albania | Tirana
Algeria | Algiers
Andorra | Andorra la Vella
Angola | Luanda
Argentina | Buenos Aires
Armenia | Yerevan
```

I need to import only country name to a list, to make it look like this:

```
['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', ...]
```

How can I do it? When I import it like this:

```
with open('countries-and-capitals.txt') as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

I get something like this:

```
['Afghanistan | Kabul','Albania | Tirana','Algeria | Algiers', ...]
```

Please, give me a hint or something like that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it on `|` and read the first part:

```py
with open('countries-and-capitals.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.split(" | ")[0] for x in content]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank You!